# How to break the for loop on mouseover google map?

Tags: angular, google-maps

On google map When I am hovering on markers I am looping the data to display in info window.

Initial time the data is coming as expected but again when hovering on same marker the data is adding with existing data.

Below I am sharing the stack blitz URL for reference:-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-google-maps-mum7rw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Please help in these issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

its not the for loop or google map issue , you need to reset the variable that is concatenating the values i.e `contentString`, on hover event set `contentString = '';`

Here is the updated code

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', () => {
        contentString = ''; //new addition
        for (let x in location.ticketSequences) {
          var items = location.ticketSequences[x];
          contentString +=
            '<b>' + items.customer + ':' + items.count + '</b> <br>';
          infowindow.setContent(contentString);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
});
```